# Biblatex foreing language example files - contribute?

Tags: biblatex, languages

Do you have a Biblatex bibliography file in a foreign language ?

We are trying to build a test-sequence for language support in Biblatex and would like to have several files, using supported and unsupported languages, so we are able to check when changes in the package, produce visible changes in the printed biblio.

We do have enough examples in English but almost none in other languages, so if you have some, send us 3 to 4 pages worth of it and any support files that will be needed to run it.

Comment: Who is "we"? And where is "sent us"?

Comment: And will this test-sequence be available to the community once you've built it? In particular, will it be published under a licence compatible with, say, TeX Live's requirements?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic since it does not ask for answers to be posted on this site. That means any responses cannot benefit the community since answers which meet the desiderata will not be available to other users.

Comment: The "we" are the maintainers of the LBX (Language files of Biblatex) files and yes, the test-files will be a part of the code-base and will be available to all under LPPL (LaTeX Project Public Li­cense), the license of BibLaTeX.